# How to change EditText look programmatically?

Tags: android, layout

I want to change default edittext look(Image:Look which i need to change) from box like look(Image:Look whic i need)...
This must be done programmatically,...I dont know how to do this...please help me

[image: Look which i need to change]

[image: Look which i needed]

Edit : Sorry typed the title wrong

Edit:Why this is not a useful question??
who voted this question down...anybody please fix this by voting up...I cant post questions

Comment: anybody please help me...why this question is not useful...I googled so many times...but I cant find any answer

Comment: I am having the "look which i needed" in other project file . But not in currently working project.I dont know what is the problem??

Comment: who voted this question down...anybody please fix this by voting up...I cant post questions..

Comment: I didn't vote, but the reason you got downvoted is probably because you didn't ask a specific question and write what you have tried so far.  Have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: How to change EditText look programmatically?
    is this not a specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a 9patch image and then set the background drawable programmatically. Please look at this tutorial and see if it's of any help.

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/changing-background-color-and-border-color-of-an-edittext-widget-using-state-list-in-android/

EDIT: doing a little more research I've found that you can get the desired look&feel by just creating a shape in drawable.xml file. You can find some samples here: http://letustech.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/customedittext/ ... then just call setBackgroundResource on the EditText to set it programmatically.

Comment: how to do this programmatically??

Comment: Link answers are discouraged, Please explain your answers in more detail.

Comment: myEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_edittext_background);

Comment: @NPE vothe this question up bro,...I cant ask question

Answer (score 0):

Create a 9 patch drawble and use that as your background.Call setBackDrawable() to use it